# Memory Leak: Reading and returning line from file

Tags: c, file, memory-leaks, fgets

I am trying to read a line from file and return the line. But, I keep getting a memory leak with 4000 bytes lost and one less free than allocs. I don't know why this is happening. Below is the function.

```
char *readLine(FILE *input, int lineNum) {

    char *string = calloc(MAX_LEN, sizeof(char));
    rewind(input);
    char *check = fgets(string, MAX_LEN, input);

    int stringLength = strlen(string);

    if (stringLength > MAX_LEN) {
        printf("Line too long to stdout.");
        free(string);
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    } else
    if (check == NULL) {
        free(string);
        return NULL;
    }
    return string;
}
```

I am calling it like this:

```
char *line = readLine(input, 0);
```

Note: ignore the `lineNum` thing, I will add it in after solving the memory leak.

So, why and where is it memory leaking? A thorough explanation would be really helpful. Thanks all!

**EDIT:** This is the function calling `readLine()`:

```
char *makeSummary(FILE *input, int summaryNum) {
   char *line = readLine(input, 0); //Get first line
   int lineLength = strlen(line);

    if (summaryNum == 1) {
        //Get the last line of file by looping till NULL
        lineNum = 10; 

        line = readLine(input, lineNum);
        //Do more stuff with line
   }
   free(line);
}
```

Comment: must free() `line' after use. But in general in C must 'design' convention for this function and strict use. C++ has additional posibilities

Comment: return EXIT_SUCCESS; is breaking your own convention

Comment: 1) `if(stringLength > MAX_LEN) {`will never be true 2) `if(check < 0) {` you are comparing a pointer to -1 here.

Comment: 1) ok, that gives me another problem to solve 2) whoops, that was mean to be  if(check == NULL). Thanks.

Comment: @JacekCz, can you please explain what you mean by breaking my own convention? Thanks

Comment: Beyond the points wildplasser makes (which are of great concern and point to a generally poor/wrong algorithm), returning `EXIT_SUCCESS` makes absolutely no sense at all. On most platforms it is equivalent to `0`, which means it is equivalent to NULL, so it goes unnoticed. But as wilplasser pointed out, that path will never be taken anyway. Further, your `strlen` would only make sense (but not much) if your `check` eval is done *first*. And it still endures that the *caller* of this function is probably not releasing *every* non-null result that comes out of it.

Comment: @WhozCraig, Oh, ok thanks, I will rewrite the check part. I understand now why the strlen path won't evaluate. Thanks.

Comment: you leak is plain as day. you read a line, if `summaryNum == 1` is true, you change the line number and read another line, blindly overwriting the prior line just-read, and therefore leaking it. And adding salt to the wound, you never check the result of the initial `readLine` call, so that ensuing `strlen` could *easily* invoke *undefined behavior* by executing on a null pointer.

Comment: @WhozCraig, Thanks that solved it :). That explanation clears up a few things for me.

Comment: if Your convention is "caller must free returned pointer if not null", You CANNOT return static string. This can give late errors in memory management. This is general C criticism, hard to design "what return to mark error",  leading to 'exception' idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some issues with your code:

- In function `readLine`, you compute the length of `string` before testing if `check == NULL`.  This is potentially incorrect.
- Furthermore, the length of `string` is by definition less than `MAX_LEN`, you test is always false.  You might want to check if the line end with a newline to detect truncation.
- You return `EXIT_SUCCESS`, but the function returns a `char *`. The compiler does not detect this discrepency because `EXIT_SUCCESS` is defined as `0` so `return EXIT_SUCCESS;` is the same as `return NULL;`.
- in the function `makeSummary`, you seem to overwrite `line` with the pointer returned by the next call to `readLine()`.  You **must** call `free(line);` before `line = readLine(input, 0)`.
- you call `rewind()` in `readLine()`, so you keep reading the same line from the input file, unless the file cannot be seeked (such as the terminal), if you are reading from a regular file, you will never reach the end.

Here is a modified version that allocates fewer bytes:

```
char *readLine(FILE *input, int lineNum) {
    char buf[MAX_LEN];
    size_t len;

    if (!fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), input)) {
        return NULL;
    }
    if ((len = strlen(buf)) == MAX_LEN - 1 && buf[len - 1] != '\n') {
        printf("Line too long from file.");
        return NULL;
    }
    return strdup(buf);
}

char *makeSummary(FILE *input, int summaryNum) {
   char *line = readLine(input, 0); //Get first line
   if (line == NULL)
       return NULL;

   int lineLength = strlen(line);

    if (summaryNum == 1) {
        //Get the last line of file by looping till NULL
        lineNum = 10; 

        free(line);
        line = readLine(input, lineNum);
        //Do more stuff with line
   }
   free(line);
   return NULL;
}
```

Note that `strdup()` is not standard and may be unavailable on non Posix systems, but is easy to implement:

```
#include <string.h>

char *strdup(const char *s) {
    size_t size = strlen(s) + 1;
    char *p = malloc(size);
    if (p != NULL) {
        memcpy(p, s, size);
    }
    return p;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that is really helpful, and thorough. Marked as answer :).

Answer (score 0):

Your function doesn't `free(string)` when it needs to return it (which makes sense), so unless some part of the code you haven't posted is `free`-ing it (and there's no way anyone here can tell, for obvious reasons), there's your leak.

Comment: line is freed later in the function that calls it when it is no longer needed. So if this is the only leak problem, what can I do to stop the leak? Sorry, I am quite new to C. Thanks

Comment: @littleCoder - edit your question with the other `free` location, since it's possible that the leak occurs at that stage. When you test for leaks, you get information about the allocating function, not the place where the leak occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all, particulary @WhozCraig. Issue was with the function using readLine didn't free Line before actually reading the line number needed. Fixed this now, all working.